# Single fluid simulation algorithm

Tags: fluid-dynamics, simulations, vacuum, computational-physics

Every fluid simulation I've seen implicitly involves a fluid that isn't mentioned, usually air. This is clear because the simulation usually has an ambient temperature, and always an ambient velocity. I can set the velocity field moving without first having added any density. So, in addition to whatever smoke or fluid I'm adding to the system, there is air that I can't get rid of.

How can I simulate a single fluid and have a vacuum? I can't find any documentation on any algorithms that do this.

Comment: Can you specify more clearly exactly what problem you want to simulate using which code? Why can't you simply set the initial conditions so that the "vacuum" regions have either zero or very low density?

Answer (score 1):

*Smoothed particle hydrodynamics* (SPH) is a fluid simulation approach that has been initially developed for astrophysics fluids (galaxies, nebula, exploding stars...), showing huge range of possible "densities", and embedded in ambient vacuum.
see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothed-particle_hydrodynamics